# How to simply obtain the sum of sizes of data members belonging to a structure?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

How to simply obtain the `sum` of sizes of data members belonging to a structure like this: 
(including padding between data members but **not** including padding between structures) ?

```
#pragma pack(4)

alignas(16) struct {
  char c[4];
  short s;
  unsigned char u[3];
} MyStruct;
```

The expression below correctly calculates this sum, but is difficult to construct since it requires the knowledge of member names, types as well as their order:

```
printf("%zu\n", &MyStruct.u[3] - &MyStruct.c[0] ); //Outputs: 11
```

The expression below does **not** calculate this sum correctly because it also counts the inter-structure padding needed to maintain alignment (the padding that **would be** needed if many such structures were put in an array).

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(MyStruct) );  //Outputs: 16
```

I realize, that the latter is by design because it facilitates pointer arithmetic.  Also, the C++ documentation states:
*"When applied to a structure/class type, the result of sizeof() is the size of an object of that structure/class plus any additional padding required to place such object in an array."*

However, that behavior of `sizeof()` makes it useless for me when dealing with single non-arrayed structures, especially when calculating the number of bytes to transmit over a network, if I do not want to transmit the **inter-structure padding** bytes...and I don't!

Note, that transmitting the inter-member padding does not bother me, because this padding is a part of the network protocol.  The protocol designers can eliminate this inter-member padding with `#pragma pack(1)` anytime they so desire ( if they did this, then the 1st printf() would output: 9 )

Comment: You need to add the size of each member individually.  Or use #pragma pack(1).

Comment: You'd need to have reflection for this, which you don't.  You really should be looking at `msgpack`, `protocol buffers`, or `Cap'n Proto` for serializing data over a network.

Comment: @zzxyx  How would reflection help ?   ...hypothetically speaking

Comment: @KarolaN - You could loop through the members of any theoretical structure, getting their sizes, serializing them, etc, without the code itself knowing anything about the structure.  As it is, the only safe thing to do is serialize each member individually.

Comment: @zzxyz  Arrghhh! I have 147 different message types in this protocol.  That's 147 different structures to serialize manually -  something that could've been done automatically by the compiler.

Comment: Treating a `struct` as a sequence of bytes is not portable in the first place.

Comment: *"The expression below correctly calculates this sum "* - no, it doesn't. Your math is wrong. The size in your first calculation is off by one octet, as you're not computing based on the +1 address of the `u` member. In short, your trimming off one octet you shouldn't be (leaving the debate of whether it is wise to do *any* of this to another comment).

Comment: @KarolaN - You might be able to get away with the approach you're trying if both sides are MSVC same chip arch.  Portably serializing data in c++ is horrible.  Sorry.  Check out the frameworks I mentioned.  They might have something that can work with your existing data.

Comment: `The expression below correctly calculates this sum...Outputs: 11` How is this correct? `4 + 2 + 3 = 9`

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right.  I corrected this.  This just shows you why I was hunting for a simpler way to calculate this...

Comment: @KillzoneKid  The compiler aligned the starting addresses of all members to be divisible by 4.  This makes the layout as follows: c: 4 bytes, s: 2 bytes, inter-member padding: 2 bytes, u: 3 bytes, inter-structure padding: 5 bytes

Comment: @KarolaN you asked for the sum of sizes, well it is 9, and that is exactly what `sizeof(MyStruct)` returns when padding is disabled

Comment: @KillzoneKid No, I stipulated *"(including padding between data members but not including padding between structures)"*  from the beginning.

Comment: FYI, You can use [`offsetof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/offsetof-macro) instead of pointer arithmetic, then you only need knowledge of the last field: `struct MyStruct { ... unsigned char u[3]; }; printf("%u\n", offsetof(MyStruct, u[3]));` Or, I like to use something like this: `#define offset_after(s_name, m_name)  (offsetof(s_name, m_name) + sizeof(s_name::m_name)) printf("%u\n", offset_after(MyStruct, u));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Still 9 https://ideone.com/2YaLJg

Comment: I would say that if you create structure that are serialized and also used in memory, then you should at least make the effort to create structures that align naturally as it will make the code more optimal. Why would you wonder for one extra byte sent over the network while unaligned data will penalize your application performance? This does not make much sense! And to ensure best portability, you have to at least have a layer to hide this from final code so that if you have to port the code on a system where data is stored differently, you could write your own code. Also use `static_assert`.

Comment: @Phil1970 Situations where 1000 additional CPU cycles cost less time than sending one extra byte over the network are common.  Also, it is not always 1 byte extra.  e.g. in my case it is 1000s of bytes extra because the buffers allocated by my network hardware are 4096bytes long (1 page long for DMA) for each datagram and the messages are rarely more than 1kB in size.  So the savings of not transmitting the inter-structure padding bytes are huge!

Comment: If the saving would be so huge, then you would not have structure with holes in them! The probability that an extra byte make the difference in the number of 4096 bytes blocks is very small. Say an object is 99 bytes instead of 100, then only if you have exactly 41 objects, you would need an extra block. So if you have between 1 and 50 objects to send, then only 2% of the time, you will loose one block. In practice, it is probably even less than that with real data. **This is premature optimization!** In any case, the extra saving will be negligible in most cases.

Comment: And `protocol buffers` or `msgpack` would probably pack the entire structure into 20 bytes *before* compression anyway and magically make (most of) your future subtle heap corruption and data alignment performance problems go away.  So you should *really* start looking at those.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: that means the `alignas (16)` is being ignored. If it weren't, `u` would be at offset 8 instead of at 6.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but `alignas` only specifies where the next structure would start, i.e. this structure start addr + 16, doesn't say anything about mandatory internal realignment, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @KillzoneKid that is true, and that would affect padding after the `u` field. However, you missed the `#pragma pack(4)` above the struct, thus making the `s` field align to 4 bytes instead of 2, affecting padding between the `s` and `u` fields, making the result 11 instead of 9

Comment: @Phil1970 In this case I wrote that the network hardware reserves 1 page of memory address space for EACH datagram.  These pages are aligned to 4096 bytes to simplify DMA and IOMMU hardware.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did not miss `#pragma pack(4)` it wasn't there. Even with it added still 9 https://ideone.com/DGrSsN